# How to Do backend and Frontend architectures in cakephp 3.0?

Tags: frontend, cakephp-3.0, backend

How separate the backend and frontend (controllers, view, layout) in the same application share the models in CakePHP 3 ?

Comment: Terms like "_tutorial_" and wording like "_I want you to do this and that for me_" will get your question closed and downvoted pretty fast. You may want to check the [**asking guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on what and how you should ask things here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `bin/cake bake` in your terminal, you can add `--prefix=Backend`

ex controller: `bin/cake bake controller NameOfYourTable --prefix=Backend`

ex template: `bin/cake bake template NameOfYourTable --prefix=Backend`

CakePHP will create the subfolder `./src/Controller/Backend/NameOfYourTable`
with the good namespace `namespace App\Controller\Backend;` and `./src/Template/Backend/NameOfYourTable/` with `index.ctp`, `add.ctp`, `edit.ctp`, `view.ctp`

And add the prefix your urls in `routes.php`

ex url: www.domain.tld/backend/nameofyourcontroller/

```
Router::prefix('backend', function($routes) {

    $routes->connect(
        '/',
        ['controller' => 'NameOfYourController', 'action' => 'index']
    );
    $routes->connect(
        '/:controller',
        ['action' => 'index'],
        ['routeClass' => 'InflectedRoute']
    );
    $routes->connect(
        '/:controller/:action/*',
        [],
        ['routeClass' => 'InflectedRoute']
    );
});
```

Comment: You're welcome @Ikbel, you can solve this post ? like http://s18.postimg.org/fgz3lf8ad/Screen_Shot_2016_03_03_at_10_02_51.png